# I'm trying to index Q7 to obtain the values of 'B' without displaying the key 'B'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
Q7 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, size = (6, 8)),\
       index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'], ['one', 'two']],\
                          names=['NUMBER', 'number']),\
       columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']],\
                          names = ['LETTER', 'letter']))
```

[image: dataframe]

Comment: The question needs more focus and detail. What is the expected output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.